# How to remove an event handler passed as a property of an object in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm using a plugin that I cannot modify directly, but I'd like to remove some event handlers from DOM elements that this plugin is attaching.

The plugin does this:

```
var openOnClick = function() {
    $('#selector').on({
        click: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            plugin.showPanel($(this));
        }
    })
};
```

It later calls `openOnClick();`

I want to remove this event completely. I tried `$('#selector').off('click')`, but this does not work. I assume this is because it is not just a simple `'click'` event attached to the `#selector`.
What are my options to get rid of this event?

Comment: `return false;` will do that, i guess.

Comment: *"I want to remove this event completely. I tried `$('#selector').off('click')`, but this does not work."* It will do, if you run it after the plugin has done the attachment you shown in your question. So if it isn't working, there's something *else* going on. *"I assume this is because it is not just a simple `'click'` event attached to the `#selector`"* Yes, it is.

Comment: T.J. Crowder. you are right. My problem was that I was trying to remove the handler before it was even added. Your comment should be an accepted answer. It is indeed a simple `click` event.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try an

```
e.stopPropagation()
```

or just an

```
return false;
```

in the body of your click handler function ?